# seeking explanation for as.Date() function in R

Tags: r

I'm converting day of year into dates, and I noticed that `as.Date` often returns unexpected (to me) results. Why do I get such different answers for these commands?

```
as.Date(x =  1, format = '%j', origin= '2015-01-01')
```

returns `"2018-07-21"`

```
as.Date(x = 1, origin= '2015-01-01')
```

returns `"2015-01-02"`

```
as.Date(x =  1, format = '%j', origin= as.Date('2015-01-01'))
```

returns `"2015-01-02"`

```
as.Date(x = '1',format = '%j', origin= '2015-01-01')
```

returns `"2018-01-01"`

```
as.Date(x = '1', origin= '2015-01-01')
```

returns an error: `Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format`

Comment: It seems there is a bug in either `as.Date` or `strptime`. Note that the last one is documented behaviour, when `x` is of class `character` you must provide a `format`. But the before last is clearly a bug, the help page says that `origin` is *"a Date object, or something which can be coerced by as.Date(origin, ...) to such an object."*

Comment: The safe way and only one that works giving the right output is `as.Date(x =  '1', format = '%j', origin= as.Date('2015-01-01'))`. Note the quotes around `'1'`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas - could you please explain your answer a little more?

Comment: When you use a character `x` you need to use `format` and `format` is only considered if `x` is a character. As for `origin= as.Date('2015-01-01')` the value `'2015-01-01'` should be coerced to `Date` automatically. It's not and I think that's a clear bug.

Comment: There aren't any bugs here; @radmuzom's answer explains how everything is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to partially answer the question below, by looking at the definition of the various `methods` under the `S3 generic as.Date`, as well as debugging your code via RStudio and looking at the history of functions called.

The definitions of `as.Date.numeric`, `as.Date.character` and `as.Date.default` are provided at the bottom of the answer.

I defined my own function `check` to debug what happens.

```
check <- function() {

as.Date(x =  1, format = '%j', origin= '2015-01-01')
as.Date(x = 1, origin= '2015-01-01')

}
```

In the first call, `UseMethod` of `as.Date` gets called, which dispatches it to `as.Date.numeric`. This is in turn calls `as.Date(origin, ...)` which now gets dispatched to `as.Date.character`. If you look at the source code of `as.Date.character`, the condition `if missing(format)` is FALSE, as the format `%j` has been provided in this case. So the piece of code which gets called is `strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT")`. This returns `2018-07-20 IST` which gets converted to `2018-07-20` by the last call to `as.Date`. Note that the time zone may vary for you depending on which country you are in. `strptime` internally calls a C function which cannot be debugged using this process.

In the second call, the main difference is that the format string was not provided by the user. So following the same process above, what gets called is the function `charToDate` defined internally within `as.Date.character` instead of `strptime` as the condition `if missing(format)` is TRUE. In this case, `charToDate` tries the default formats and finds a match in `'%Y-%m-%d`. In this case, `strptime` is provided the *correct* format and computes the correct value `2015-01-01`. This is now added to `x`, which is 1 - remember the character version was called by the numeric version where the code was `as.Date(origin, ...) + x`. This provides the *correct* answer.

While it does not provide a complete answer to your question, the general learning is that it is heavily dependent on the format string being passed to `strptime`. Hope this helps.

**as.Date.numeric**

```
function (x, origin, ...)
{
  if (missing(origin))
    stop("'origin' must be supplied")
  as.Date(origin, ...) + x
}
```

**as.Date.character**

```
function (x, format, tryFormats = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%Y/%m/%d"),
          optional = FALSE, ...)
{
  charToDate <- function(x) {
    xx <- x[1L]
    if (is.na(xx)) {
      j <- 1L
      while (is.na(xx) && (j <- j + 1L) <= length(x)) xx <- x[j]
      if (is.na(xx))
        f <- "%Y-%m-%d"
    }
    if (is.na(xx))
      strptime(x, f)
    else {
      for (ff in tryFormats) if (!is.na(strptime(xx, ff,
                                                 tz = "GMT")))
        return(strptime(x, ff))
      if (optional)
        as.Date.character(rep.int(NA_character_, length(x)),
                          "%Y-%m-%d")
      else stop("character string is not in a standard unambiguous format")
    }
  }
  res <- if (missing(format))
    charToDate(x)
  else strptime(x, format, tz = "GMT")
  as.Date(res)
}
```

**as.Date.default**

```
function (x, ...)
{
  if (inherits(x, "Date"))
    x
  else if (is.logical(x) && all(is.na(x)))
    .Date(as.numeric(x))
  else stop(gettextf("do not know how to convert '%s' to class %s",
                     deparse(substitute(x)), dQuote("Date")), domain = NA)
}
```

Comment: This answer is very complete.  A short version:  if `x` is numeric, `format` is only used for `origin`.  If `x` is character, `origin` is ignored.